# How do I resolve error "No bean of type [io.micronaut.data.operations.PrimaryRepositoryOperations] exists" in micronaut application?

Tags: micronaut, micronaut-data

I am evaluating micronaut and am attempting to port a small application as a pilot project.  I have run into a snag dealing with datasources/repositories.

I have the following application.yml:

```
micronaut:
  application:
    name: bling-application

datasources:
  default:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
    username: sa
    password: ''
    schema-generate: CREATE_DROP
    dialect: H2

jpa:
  default:
    entity-scan:
      packages: 'my.package.entity'
    properties:
      hibernate:
        bytecode:
          provider: none
        hbm2ddl:
          auto: update
```

I have defined a simple Repository interface as follows:

```
package my.package.entity.repository;

import my.package.entity.Company;
import io.micronaut.data.annotation.Repository;
import io.micronaut.data.repository.CrudRepository;

@Repository
public interface CompanyRepository extends CrudRepository<Company, Long> {

    Company findByName(String name);

}
```

When I run the application in test mode (`./mvnw compile exec:exec`) it starts without error.  However, when I request an end-point that exercises the CompanyRepository I receive the following exception:

```
14:38:37.307 [pool-1-thread-4] ERROR i.m.h.s.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler - Unexpected error occurred: No backing RepositoryOperations configured for repository. Check your configuration and try again
io.micronaut.context.exceptions.ConfigurationException: No backing RepositoryOperations configured for repository. Check your configuration and try again
        at io.micronaut.data.intercept.DataIntroductionAdvice.findInterceptor(DataIntroductionAdvice.java:109)
        at io.micronaut.data.intercept.DataIntroductionAdvice.intercept(DataIntroductionAdvice.java:77)
        at io.micronaut.aop.chain.MethodInterceptorChain.proceed(MethodInterceptorChain.java:69)
        at my.package.entity.repository.CompanyRepository$Intercepted.findByName(Unknown Source)
        at my.package.bling.BlingExportBean.getProductionCompanyByName(BlingExportBean.java:519)
        at my.package.bling.BlingExportBean.doExport(BlingExportBean.java:167)
        at my.package.bling.BlingExportBean.export(BlingExportBean.java:112)
        at my.package.bling.BlingExportResource.export(BlingExportResource.java:20)
        at my.package.bling.$BlingExportResourceDefinition$$exec1.invokeInternal(Unknown Source)
        at io.micronaut.context.AbstractExecutableMethod.invoke(AbstractExecutableMethod.java:147)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext$BeanExecutionHandle.invoke(DefaultBeanContext.java:2844)
        at io.micronaut.web.router.AbstractRouteMatch.execute(AbstractRouteMatch.java:235)
        at io.micronaut.web.router.RouteMatch.execute(RouteMatch.java:122)
        at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler.lambda$buildResultEmitter$17(RoutingInBoundHandler.java:1400)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableCreate.subscribeActual(FlowableCreate.java:71)
        at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
        at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14865)
        at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.RxInstrumentedFlowable.subscribeActual(RxInstrumentedFlowable.java:68)
        at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableMap.subscribeActual(FlowableMap.java:37)
        at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
        at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14865)
        at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.RxInstrumentedFlowable.subscribeActual(RxInstrumentedFlowable.java:68)
        at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableSwitchIfEmpty.subscribeActual(FlowableSwitchIfEmpty.java:32)
        at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
        at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14865)
        at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.RxInstrumentedFlowable.subscribeActual(RxInstrumentedFlowable.java:68)
        at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
        at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14868)
        at io.micronaut.http.context.ServerRequestTracingPublisher.lambda$subscribe$0(ServerRequestTracingPublisher.java:52)
        at io.micronaut.http.context.ServerRequestContext.with(ServerRequestContext.java:52)
        at io.micronaut.http.context.ServerRequestTracingPublisher.subscribe(ServerRequestTracingPublisher.java:52)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFromPublisher.subscribeActual(FlowableFromPublisher.java:29)
        at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
        at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14865)
        at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.RxInstrumentedFlowable.subscribeActual(RxInstrumentedFlowable.java:68)
        at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14918)
        at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14865)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber.run(FlowableSubscribeOn.java:82)
        at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ExecutorScheduler$ExecutorWorker$BooleanRunnable.run(ExecutorScheduler.java:288)
        at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ExecutorScheduler$ExecutorWorker.run(ExecutorScheduler.java:253)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: io.micronaut.context.exceptions.NoSuchBeanException: No bean of type [io.micronaut.data.operations.PrimaryRepositoryOperations] exists. Make sure the bean is not disabled by bean requirements (enable trace logging for 'io.micronaut.context.condition' to check) and if the bean is enabled then ensure the class is declared a bean and annotation processing is enabled (for Java and Kotlin the 'micronaut-inject-java' dependency should be configured as an annotation processor).
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanInternal(DefaultBeanContext.java:1974)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:610)
        at io.micronaut.data.intercept.DataIntroductionAdvice.findInterceptor(DataIntroductionAdvice.java:106)
        ... 44 common frames omitted
```

The stack trace says that something is missing from the application context (presumably PrimaryRepositoryOperations) but it is not clear to me what that is.  How can I correct this error?  I am new to micronaut and presume that I am missing some crucial dependency or configuration.

For additional context my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>bling.application</groupId>
  <artifactId>bling-application</artifactId>
  <version>0.1</version>
  <properties>
    <micronaut.version>1.2.9</micronaut.version>
    <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
    <maven.compiler.target>${jdk.version}</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>${jdk.version}</maven.compiler.source>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <exec.mainClass>my.package.bling.Application</exec.mainClass>
    <maven-surefire-plugin.version>2.22.2</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
    <maven-failsafe-plugin.version>2.22.2</maven-failsafe-plugin.version>
    <mans-core.version>1.0.16-SNAPSHOT</mans-core.version>
    <okhttp.version>3.11.0</okhttp.version>
  </properties>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>jcenter.bintray.com</id>
      <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
        <artifactId>micronaut-bom</artifactId>
        <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
      <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
      <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
      <version>${okhttp.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-inject</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-validation</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-runtime</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-http-server-netty</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-http-client</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.data</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-data-hibernate-jpa</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.M5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.configuration</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-hibernate-jpa</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.3</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.test</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-test-junit5</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <transformers>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                  <mainClass>${exec.mainClass}</mainClass>
                </transformer>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
              </transformers>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <executable>java</executable>
          <arguments>
            <argument>-classpath</argument>
            <classpath/>
            <argument>-noverify</argument>
            <argument>-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1</argument>
            <argument>-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote</argument>
            <argument>${exec.mainClass}</argument>
          </arguments>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
          <configuration>
            <detail>true</detail>
            <includes>
              <include>%regex[.*]</include>
            </includes>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${maven-failsafe-plugin.version}</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                <goal>verify</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <compilerArgs>
              <arg>-parameters</arg>
            </compilerArgs>
            <annotationProcessorPaths>
              <path>
                <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
                <artifactId>micronaut-inject-java</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.9</version>
              </path>
              <path>
                <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
                <artifactId>micronaut-validation</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.9</version>
              </path>
              <path>
                <groupId>io.micronaut.data</groupId>
                <artifactId>micronaut-data-processor</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0.M5</version>
              </path>
            </annotationProcessorPaths>
          </configuration>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>test-compile</id>
              <goals>
                <goal>testCompile</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <compilerArgs>
                  <arg>-parameters</arg>
                </compilerArgs>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                  <path>
                    <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
                    <artifactId>micronaut-inject-java</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.9</version>
                  </path>
                  <path>
                    <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
                    <artifactId>micronaut-validation</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.9</version>
                  </path>
                  <path>
                    <groupId>io.micronaut.data</groupId>
                    <artifactId>micronaut-data-processor</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0.M5</version>
                  </path>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 6):

I had the same error and it was caused by incorrect package name in the `entity-scan` property.

Like this sample:

```
jpa:
  default:
    entity-scan:
      packages: 'your.package.domain'
```

Answer (score 4):

Okay, one more answer which maybe helpful in this particular case that I was facing. So I had a service which was not being injected after I applied the validation annotations. So, the fix as clearly mentioned on the docs page is:

https://docs.micronaut.io/snapshot/guide/index.html#datavalidation

**For Gradle**

```
implementation("io.micronaut.beanvalidation:micronaut-hibernate-validator")
```

**For Maven:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.micronaut.beanvalidation</groupId>
    <artifactId>micronaut-hibernate-validator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was missing/conflicting dependencies in my pom file.  To resolve I added this dependency:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.configuration</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-jdbc-tomcat</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

And removed this one:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.configuration</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-hibernate-jpa</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an event listener that queries the database on application startup. If the DB is unreachable, it also throws this exception.
`No bean of type [io.micronaut.data.operations.PrimaryRepositoryOperations] exists` .

```
@Singleton
open class NativeUserAuthorization(
        private val userService: UserServiceOperations): ApplicationEventListener<ServerStartupEvent> {

    override fun onApplicationEvent(event: ServerStartupEvent?) {
        // database access here
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I tried the dependencies EXACTLY as in one of the projects in https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-data and it worked.

These projects are a good starting place too.

Comment: This link on github is broken

Comment: Updated broken link.