# No backing RepositoryOperations configured for repository. Check your configuration and try again

Tags: java, micronaut, micronaut-data

Trying to use `RxJavaCrudRepository` with Micronaut data with mongo db.

```
@Repository
public interface GenericRepository extends RxJavaCrudRepository<Product, Long> {
}
```

Getting the value from repository

```
private final GenericRepository repository;

    public ProductListener(GenericRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }
    var item = this.repository.findAll();
```

Dependency

```
implementation("io.micronaut.data:micronaut-data-hibernate-jpa")
    implementation("io.micronaut.mongodb:micronaut-mongo-reactive")
```

Exception

> io.micronaut.context.exceptions.ConfigurationException: No backing
> RepositoryOperations configured for repository. Check your
> configuration and try again
>
> io.micronaut.context.exceptions.NoSuchBeanException: No bean of type
> [io.micronaut.data.operations.PrimaryRepositoryOperations] exists.
> Make sure the bean is not disabled by bean requirements (enable trace
> logging for 'io.micronaut.context.condition' to check) and if the bean
> is enabled then ensure the class is declared a bean and annotation
> processing is enabled (for Java and Kotlin the 'micronaut-inject-java'
> dependency should be configured as an annotation processor).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve error "No bean of type \[io.micronaut.data.operations.PrimaryRepositoryOperations\] exists" in micronaut application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59777918/how-do-i-resolve-error-no-bean-of-type-io-micronaut-data-operations-primaryrep)

Comment: No actually not, if I remove implementation("io.micronaut.data:micronaut-data-hibernate-jpa") then I get an exception on RxJavaCrudRepository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the MongoClient not a repository.

See for example here:

https://github.com/ilopmar/micronaut-mongo-reactive-sample/blob/master/src/main/java/mongoreactive/MongoController.java

Or here:

http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver-reactivestreams/1.9/javadoc/com/mongodb/reactivestreams/client/MongoClient.html

I guess repositories are not supporting mongodb. Thats why you get the exception, cause no real database is there to be used with the repo.

Comment: Yes, the repository is not available for mongo till yet